# Strange behavior of subsubsection

Tags: spacing, sectioning, parallel

I create a questionnaire (Question-Answer). For this purpose I use the pdfcolparallel package. When I type `\subsubsection` in the first column, a strange vertical line appears before subsubsection and the top border. I suppose it is connected with using subsubsection, because without it everything works ok. The same problem appears with the `itemize` enviroment. Could you explain to me thy this happens and if there are any existing workarounds?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=1.2cm, bottom=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\setkeys{parallel}{rulebetweencolor=black}
%%%%%%%%%%% layout
\voffset = 0pt
\hoffset = 0pt
\headheight = 35pt
\headsep = 0.4cm
\footskip = 0.7cm
\oddsidemargin = -14pt 
\topskip=0.7cm
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\hyphenpenalty 10000

%%%%%%%%%%% Header-Footer style


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~\@cftasnumb%
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{MySpecHeaderColor}{RGB}{219,132,0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\textcolor{black}{#1}}{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}

% itemize enviroment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%section/subsection/subsubsection numbering
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{15}{20}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}\normalfont}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}\normalfont}


\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{-7.5pt}{-16pt}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{MySpecHeaderColor}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Text}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{framed}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{6cm}{10cm}
\ParallelLText{\subsubsection{rague Experience is your complete Prague tourist information and travel guide.
We are the original online Prague city guide and booking service, and over the past 11 years we have built a lot of useful visitor information into this website.
}}
\ParallelRText{
You can browse through our exclusive deals on Prague hotels and apartments, arrange airport transfers, and book tickets for the best Prague sightseeing trips and entertainment.
We feature a range of Prague tours, including sightseeing tours by coach, walking tours and leisurely Prague river cruises. And we provide listings for the Prague opera, ballet and classical concerts, plus black light and marionette theatre.
Read our guide to Prague restaurants for all budgets, and discover our great package deals on Prague city breaks, Prague stag weekends and Prague hen nights.
Booking is easy, with information fully encrypted on our secure servers.
You can browse through our exclusive deals on Prague hotels and apartments, arrange airport transfers, and book tickets for the best Prague sightseeing trips and entertainment.
We feature a range of Prague tours, including sightseeing tours by coach, walking tours and leisurely Prague river cruises. And we provide listings for the Prague opera, ballet and classical concerts, plus black light and marionette theatre.
Read our guide to Prague restaurants for all budgets, and discover our great package deals on Prague city breaks, Prague stag weekends and Prague hen nights.
Booking is easy, with information fully encrypted on our secure servers.
}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\ParallelLText{\subsubsection{rague Experience is your complete Prague tourist information and travel guide.
We are the original online Prague city guide and booking service, and over the past 11 years we have built a lot of useful visitor information into this website.
}}
\ParallelRText{
You can browse through our exclusive deals on Prague hotels and apartments, arrange airport transfers, and book tickets for the best Prague sightseeing trips and entertainment.
We feature a range of Prague tours, including sightseeing tours by coach, walking tours and leisurely Prague river cruises. And we provide listings for the Prague opera, ballet and classical concerts, plus black light and marionette theatre.
Read our guide to Prague restaurants for all budgets, and discover our great package deals on Prague city breaks, Prague stag weekends and Prague hen nights.
Booking is easy, with information fully encrypted on our secure servers.
You can browse through our exclusive deals on Prague hotels and apartments, arrange airport transfers, and book tickets for the best Prague sightseeing trips and entertainment.
We feature a range of Prague tours, including sightseeing tours by coach, walking tours and leisurely Prague river cruises. And we provide listings for the Prague opera, ballet and classical concerts, plus black light and marionette theatre.
Read our guide to Prague restaurants for all budgets, and discover our great package deals on Prague city breaks, Prague stag weekends and Prague hen nights.
Booking is easy, with information fully encrypted on our secure servers.
\\
\\
}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
\end {framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lopes, a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Adding a `\leavevmode` before the `\subsubsection` command will ensure that rule gets put into place, but you still get unwanted vertical space in the right hand column.  I would consider just writing these titles as `\textbf{....}` instead.

Comment: Unwanted vertical space in the right hand column and vertical line are here. Only after \leavevmode the height of line decreased

Answer (score 5):

Package `parallel` has simple text in mind that can be divided in single lines, but `\subsubsection` is rather complex. There are color whatsits and whatsits for `hyperref`'s anchors that goes into the vertical list. Then `parallel` splits the list to get a line and gets whatsits without width, thus that the vertical line is moved to the left.

### Workaround `\parbox`

The following example shows the problem in a much smaller file and puts the `\subsubsection` into a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}[v]{6cm}{10cm}
\hrule
\ParallelLText{%
  \subsubsection{Experience complete with Prague tourist information}%
}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\ParallelLText{%
  \vspace*{-1.5ex}%
  \noindent
  \parbox[b]{6cm}{%
    \subsubsection{Experience complete with Prague tourist information}%
  }%
}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The `\vspace*{-1ex}` removes a little of the additional space by `\subsubsection` for example.

`\parbox` is not breakable, thus the right part is not filled with text lines.

### Workaround patching `parallel`

Package `parallel` puts the line that is split from the vertical list into a `\vbox` and assumes the line width will set the width of `\vbox`. Since the assumption does not hold for all cases, the following patch puts a `\hbox` of the correct width around the `\vbox`. The example redefines `\ParallelParOnePage` of package `pdfcolparallel`, but the problem is already inherited from package `parallel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ParallelParOnePage}{%
  \ifnum\ParallelBoolVar=\@ne
    \par
    \begingroup
      \leftmargin=\z@
      \rightmargin=\z@
      \parskip=\z@skip
      \parindent=\z@
      \vbadness=10000 %
      \vfuzz=3ex %
      \splittopskip=\z@skip
      \loop
        \ifnum\ParallelBoolVar=\@ne
          \noindent
          \hbox to\textwidth{%
            \hskip\ParallelLeftMargin
            \hbox to\ParallelTextWidth{%
              \ifvoid\ParallelLBox
                \hskip\ParallelLWidth
              \else
                \pcp@SetCurrent{Left}%
                \ParallelWhichBox=\z@
                \hbox to \ParallelLWidth{%
                  \vbox{%
                    \setbox\ParallelBoxVar
                        =\vsplit\ParallelLBox to\dp\strutbox
                    \unvbox\ParallelBoxVar
                  }%
                \hss
                }%
              \fi
              \strut
              \ifnum\ParallelBoolMid=\@ne
                \hskip\ParallelMainMidSkip
                \begingroup
                  \pcp@RuleBetweenColor
                  \vrule
                \endgroup
              \else
                \hss
              \fi
              \hss
              \ifvoid\ParallelRBox
                \hskip\ParallelRWidth
              \else
                \pcp@SetCurrent{Right}%
                \ParallelWhichBox=\@ne
                \vbox{%
                  \setbox\ParallelBoxVar
                      =\vsplit\ParallelRBox to\dp\strutbox
                  \unvbox\ParallelBoxVar
                }%
              \fi
            }%
          }%
          \ifvoid\ParallelLBox
            \ifvoid\ParallelRBox
              \global\ParallelBoolVar=\z@
            \fi
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \ifnum\ParallelBoolVar=\@ne
        \penalty\interlinepenalty
      \repeat
      \par
    \endgroup
    \pcp@SetCurrent{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}[v]{6cm}{10cm}
\hrule
\ParallelLText{%
  \subsubsection{Experience complete with Prague tourist information}%
}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Now the vertical line is moved correctly in the middle, but there is a gap and the stuff, which `\subsubsection` puts *before* its actual title causes another problem. Package `parallel` can now split of a visual empty line (whatsits, vertical space) before the subsubsection title and this empty line is matched with a text line to the right.

### Workaround with simulated `\subsubsection`

A better way is here probably to put the section title manually as text
as proposed by Andrew Swann in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148290/strange-behavior-of-subsubsection#comment336744_148290) to the question.

The following example defines `\parallelsubsubsection` with the same syntax as `\subsubsection` with star form and optional argument. It also takes care of the hanging indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\parallelsubsubsection}{%
  \@ifstar\parallelsubsubsection@star
          \parallelsubsubsection@
}
\newcommand*{\parallelsubsubsection@star}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \textbf{#1}%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\parallelsubsubsection@}{%
  \@dblarg\parallelsubsubsection@@
}
\def\parallelsubsubsection@@[#1]#2{%
  \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
    \bfseries
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#1}%
    \sbox0{\thesubsubsection\enskip}%
    \hangafter=1\relax
    \setlength{\hangindent}{\wd0}%
    \thesubsubsection\enskip#2\par
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{6cm}{10cm}
\hrule
\ParallelLText{%
  \parallelsubsubsection{%
    Experience complete with Prague tourist information%
  }%
}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Might you be able to help with this question as well? --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420361/121944, You seem well suited to answer it.

Comment: @AML The example there uses packages and fonts that I do not know/have.

Comment: I have added a simpler MWE. Hopefully it works for you.