# Polyglot interlinear bible verses(rows) don't break but begin on new page

Tags: page-breaking, expex, parcolumns

I'm looking for help! 
I used `\usepackage{parcolumns}` in order to manage splittings inside parallel verses
on the same page. Here is the sample

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}        
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,headsep=0.2cm,footskip=0.5cm}

\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=6cm,3=7cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{{\bf 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 1.} \blindtext}
\end{parcolumns}

\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=6cm,3=7cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{{\bf 2.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 2.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 2.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bf 2.} \blindtext}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

And I got image1:[image: image1 we have a nice <code>pagebreak</code> in the verse itself]

However if in `parcolumns` I insert the interlinear verses through `\usepackage{expex}` with `gla` option
it seems that there is no `pagebreak` in the verse itself! e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}   

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,headsep=0.2cm,footskip=0.5cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}
%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{parcolumns}


\font\Shlomofnt="Shlomo" at 14pt
\font\Time="Times New Roman:color=FF0000" at 11pt
\font\Timeb="Times New Roman:color=0000FF" at 11pt
\font\greek="CMU Serif" at 12.7pt 
\lingset{
    everygla=\Shlomofnt,
    everyglb=\Time,aboveglbskip=-0.8ex,
    everyglc=\Timeb,aboveglcskip=-0.8ex,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Genesis}
\section{Chapter 1}

%%%%%
\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=7cm,3=6cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{\begingl\beginR
\gla   בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃  //
\glb bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets //
\glc \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} //
\endgl
}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek] 
\gla \textcolor{red}{{\bf 1.}} De‑nceput făcu Dumnedzău ceriul şi pămîntul. \textcolor{red}{{\bf 1.}} ΕΝ ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ Θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. \textcolor{red}{{\bf 1.}} В начале сотворил Бог небо и землю.//
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {1. εν} {αρχή} {εποίησεν} {ο θεός} {τον} {ουρανόν} {και} {την} {γην}//
\glc 
{In} 
{the beginning }
{made} {God}
{the}
{heaven}
{and}
{the}
{earth.}//
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {1. εν} {αρχή} {εποίησεν} {ο θεός} {τον} {ουρανόν} {και} {την} {γην}//
\glc 
{In} 
{the beginning }
{made} {God}
{the}
{heaven}
{and}
{the}
{earth.}//
\endgl}
\end{parcolumns}

%%%%%
\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=7cm,3=6cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{\begingl\beginR
\gla   בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃  //
\glb bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets //
\glc \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} //
\endgl
}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek] \gla 1. De‑nceput făcu Dumnedzău ceriul şi pămîntul. + 1 В начале сотворил Бог небо и землю. + 1. ΕΝ ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ Θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. //
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {1. εν} {αρχή} {εποίησεν} {ο θεός} {τον} {ουρανόν} {και} {την} {γην}//
\glc 
{In} 
{the beginning }
{made} {God}
{the}
{heaven}
{and}
{the}
{earth.}//
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {1. εν} {αρχή} {εποίησεν} {ο θεός} {τον} {ουρανόν} {και} {την} {γην}//
\glc 
{In} 
{the beginning }
{made} {God}
{the}
{heaven}
{and}
{the}
{earth.}//
\endgl}
\end{parcolumns}
%%%%%%
\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=7cm,3=6cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{\begingl\beginR
\gla    וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל־ פְּנֵי תְהוֹם וְרוּחַ אֱלֹהִים מְרַחֶפֶת עַל־ פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם׃ וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל־ פְּנֵי תְהוֹם וְרוּחַ אֱלֹהִים מְרַחֶפֶת עַל־ פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם׃ //
\glb  vehaarets haita tohu vavohu vehoshek al pene tehom  veruah elohim merahepet al pene hammaim vehaarets haita tohu vavohu vehoshek al pene tehom  veruah elohim merahepet al pene hammaim //
\glc  \LR{And the earth} \LR{was} \LR{without form} \LR{and void} \LR{and darkness} \LR{[was] on} \LR{the face} \LR{of the deep} \LR{And the Spirit} \LR{of God} \LR{moved} \LR{on} \LR{the face} \LR{of the waters} \LR{And the earth} \LR{was} \LR{without form} \LR{and void} \LR{and darkness} \LR{[was] on} \LR{the face} \LR{of the deep} \LR{And the Spirit} \LR{of God} \LR{moved} \LR{on} \LR{the face} \LR{of the waters}//
\endgl
}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek] 
\gla 2. Iară pămîntul era nevădzut şi netocmit. Şi întunêrec dzăcea deasupra preste cel fără de fundu şi Duhul lui Dumnedzău să purta pre deasupra apei.
2 Земля же была безвидна и пуста, и тьма над бездною, и Дух Божий носился над водою. 2 ἡ δὲ γῆ ἦν ἀόρατος καὶ ἀκατασκεύαστος, καὶ σκότος ἐπάνω τῆς ἀβύσσου, καὶ πνεῦμα Θεοῦ ἐπεφέρετο ἐπάνω τοῦ ὕδατος. //
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {2. η δε} {γη} {ην} {αόρατος} {και} {ακατασκεύαστος} {και} {σκότος}
{επάνω} 
{της}
{αβύσσου}
{και}
{πνεύμα}
{θεού}
{επεφέρετο}
{επάνω}
{του}
{ύδατος}//
\glc 
{But the}
{earth}
{was}
{unseen}
{and}
{unready}
{and}
{darkness}
{was upon}
{the}
{abyss}
{and}
{Spirit}
{of God}
{bore }
{upon}
{the}
{water}//
\endgl}
\colchunk{\begingl[everygla=\greek]
\gla {2. η δε} {γη} {ην} {αόρατος} {και} {ακατασκεύαστος} {και} {σκότος}
{επάνω} 
{της}
{αβύσσου}
{και}
{πνεύμα}
{θεού}
{επεφέρετο}
{επάνω}
{του}
{ύδατος}//
\glc 
{But the}
{earth}
{was}
{unseen}
{and}
{unready}
{and}
{darkness}
{was upon}
{the}
{abyss}
{and}
{Spirit}
{of God}
{bore }
{upon}
{the}
{water}//
\endgl}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

And I got image2:
[image]
What we see in image1 we have a nice `pagebreak` in the verse itself, mean wile on image2 there is not(we have a big white space skip)!
Thus, how to break interlinear verses that use `gla` in order to get the same `pagebreak` as in image1.
maybe someone can help to handle it?

**Update!**

I will not open other questions because some will say that is a duplicate,
as I mentioned in my comment to @AML using `glbreaking` is solving PARTIALLY my problem
because I'm getting  this image3
[image: image3]
it's ok, however, on image3 we have white spaces on the 2,3 and 4rth columns!!!
thus to be most clear, I appreciate the solution of @AML with `glbreaking` but I'm expecting as well that:

on first column to have Hebrew, transliteration and translation(thus 3 rows it's OK),

on the second column I will chose my native language only, without transliteration and translation(thus I don't need  2 rows of white spaces which are reserved for transliteration and translation!!!),

and on the third and fourth columns to have Greek and his translation without transliteration (thus I don't need the white row for transliteration! )

Thus I prefer this image4 like I posted in my code above
[image: image4]

rather than this image5
[image: image5]

If possible, @AML can you please find a solution and make changes in your answer and update it?

Comment: Use the `glbreaking` feature of `expex` under your `lingset`. You might need to download the newer version of `expex` if it's been a while for you. https://ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en

Comment: As a side note, I do not recommend transliterating both `ה` and `ח` with the letter `h`. They make different sounds from each other in both Biblical and Modern Hebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `glbreaking` under `lingset`, then you get the solution that I believe you're looking for. Note, the Hebrew words are in reverse order, but you get the idea. The important issue here is the `pagebreak`. Also, use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf` (explainer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)).

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}   

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,headsep=0.2cm,footskip=0.5cm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\LARGE,
    everyglb=\englishfont,
    everyglc=\englishfont,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glbreaking % add this. Download new version of expex if needed at https://ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en
}

\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=6cm,3=7cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{%
\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. //
\endgl\end{hebrew}
}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\end{parcolumns}

\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=8.5cm,2=6cm,3=7cm,4=6cm}]{4}
\colchunk{%
\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. //
\endgl\end{hebrew}
}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\colchunk{{\bfseries 1.} \blindtext}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

**Without `glbreaking`:**

[image]

**With `glbreaking`:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I think `paracol` solves your remaining issue. There are many multiple column packages, and some play better than others with `expex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}   

\usepackage{libertine}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,headsep=0.2cm,footskip=0.5cm}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \setotherlanguage{greek}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\LARGE,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glbreaking % Download new version of expex if needed at https://ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\setcolumnwidth{8.5cm,7cm,6cm,6cm} 

\begin{paracol}{4} % this is what I want
  \sloppy\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. //
\glb bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets //
\glc \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.}  //
\endgl\end{hebrew}
  \switchcolumn[1]
  \sloppy\blindtext
  \switchcolumn[2]
  \sloppy\begin{greek}\begingl
\gla Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} //
\glc In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} //
\endgl\end{greek}
  \switchcolumn[3]
  \sloppy\lipsum[1-2]
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{4} % this is what I want
  \sloppy\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. //
\glb bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets bereshit bara elohim et hashamaim veet haarets //
\glc \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.} \LR{In the beginning} \LR{created} \LR{God} {} \LR{the heavens} \LR{and} \LR{the earth.}  //
\endgl\end{hebrew}
  \switchcolumn[1]
  \sloppy\blindtext
  \switchcolumn[2]
  \sloppy\begin{greek}\begingl
\gla Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} Εν αρχή εποίησεν ο Θεός {τον ουρανόν} και {την γην} //
\glc In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} In {the beginning} made {} God {the heaven} and {the earth} //
\endgl\end{greek}
  \switchcolumn[3]
  \sloppy\lipsum[1-2]
\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated `expex` now `glbreaking` is working, however, how we can ignore
white spaces on the 2,3 and 4rth columns? maybe is possible to use newcommand `\ignorespaces` like in this post:
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424832/alignment-issue-with-glbreaking-gloss-breaking-in-expex`

Comment: You should ask a new question. But also why would you want to ignore it? Don't you want each verse to line up? Seems like they would quickly get out of alignment. Also, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I think `expex` and `parcolumns` don't play well together. See my old question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420361/parcolumns-spacing-problem-when-used-with-expex. I think you could make all this look nice with `parbox`es, but they don't `pagebreak`. So if you really need pagebreaking, then I suggest you post a new question with a better MWE that people can play with.

Comment: I updated my answer to add a `paracol` option that helps with the additional issue.